# Overflow property doesn't seem to work on navigation links' animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I have this test page.
As you can see from the demo, I want the menu bar with the links to disappear to the right when the burger icon is not toggled, but `overflow: hidden;` doesn't seem to work.

Also, I noticed that if I hide the menu on the LEFT, so with a negative value: `transform: translatex(-120%);` instead of: `transform: translatex(120%);` I don't have this problem even without specifying `overflow: hidden;`.

I also tried giving a width to the body, 'cause I thought "how can it know where to stop 'spilling' content if I don't tell it?", but *quiz-show wrong answer sound*. :)

What am I doing wrong?

(By the way, this is the first time posting a snippet with some JS inside! Feel powerful :) )

```js
let toggleButton = document.getElementById('burger')
let navBarLinks = document.getElementById('nav1')

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navBarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

:root {
  font-size: 15px;
}


header {
  margin-bottom: -180px;

}

.logoandburger {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,lightpink,powderblue);
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.burger {
  position: absolute;
  left: 85%;
}

.bubbles {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  left: -20px;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes bubbly {
  from {
    transform: scale(.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.9);
    opacity: 1;
  }

}

.burger:active ~ .bubbles {
  display: block;
  animation: bubbly .2s linear;
}


.nav1 {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,powderblue,lightpink);
  text-align: center;
  transform: translatex(120%);
  transition: .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.nav1.active {
  transform: translatex(0%);
}

ul {
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<header id="nav2">
    <div class="logoandburger">
      <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
      <img src="menu.svg" class="burger" id="burger" width="35px;" alt="menu icon">
      <img src="bubble.svg" class="bubbles" width="30px" alt="">
    </div>
    <nav class="nav1" id="nav1">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas officia eligendi! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas o illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas officia eligendi! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus volupt</h1>
<script src="main.js">

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```js
let toggleButton = document.getElementById('burger')
let navBarLinks = document.getElementById('nav1')

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navBarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

:root {
    font-size: 15px;
}


header {
    margin-bottom: -180px;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}

.logoandburger {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,lightpink,powderblue);
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.burger {
    position: absolute;
    left: 85%;
}

.bubbles {
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    left: -20px;
    display: none;
}

@keyframes bubbly {
    from {
        transform: scale(.5);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1.9);
        opacity: 1;
    }

}

.burger:active ~ .bubbles {
    display: block;
    animation: bubbly .2s linear;
}


.nav1 {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,powderblue,lightpink);
    text-align: center;
    transform: translatex(120%);
    transition: .5s;
}


.nav1.active {
    transform: translatex(0%);
}

ul {
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding: 1em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a {
    color: black;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header id="nav2">
        <div class="logoandburger">
            <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
            <img src="menu.svg" class="burger" id="burger" width="35px;" alt="menu icon">
            <img src="bubble.svg" class="bubbles" width="30px" alt="">
        </div>
        <nav class="nav1" id="nav1">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas officia eligendi! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas o illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas officia eligendi! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus voluptas ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At ut animi dicta ex, optio illo id perferendis ipsum quia repellat quam quis aut vel fugiat alias mollitia, architecto quos, delectus, eos. Blanditiis accusantium eum, culpa, dolores delectus volupt</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to understand that `<header>` is overflowing not `<nav class="nav1" id="nav1">`. Also overflow is happening horizontally only.

Inside CSS, you just need to remove `overflow: hidden;` from your `.nav1` and add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your `header`.